# Why won't my link navigate to the page that I want upon clicking it?

Tags: python, django

In Chrome, I must manually type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/1/` in order to get to the page that I want.  (I want to go to page 1).

However, When I try to click the link that I thought would take me to where I want in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/music`, for example, Red.  It takes me to that error page:

[image][image]

Here's my `views.py`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import loader
from .models import Album

def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('music/index.html')
    context = {
        'all_albums': all_albums,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for album id: " + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

Here's my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),

    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
]
```

Here's my `index.html

```
    {% if all_albums %} <!-- Will be true as long as it has at least 1 album -->
    <h3>Here are all my albums</h3>
<ul>
    {% for album in all_albums %}
    <li><a href="/music/id/{{ album.id }}">{{ album.album_title }}</a></li>
    {%  endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>You don't have any albums</h3>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: How did you write the url in your template for the ``Red``? Is it something like ``{% url 'your_app_name:detail' album_id %}``?

Comment: @Liliane I posted my index.html file

Comment: If you change the link to ``/music/{{ album.id }}/`` does it lands you on a correct page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in the template. Instead of `/music/id/{{ album.id }}` you should have `/music/{{ album.id }}/`. When you hit the link `Red` it redirects you to `music/id/1` instead of `music/1`. So you get a 404 error.

Comment: Wow so simple!  Thanks a lot :D

Comment: @bojack you should consider adding ``app_name='[put the actual name of your app here]'`` before ``urlpatterns``. That way you could construct links as ``{% url 'your_app_name:detail' album_id %}``. I recommend you go through official [Django polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) (it has seven parts).